# Nested Member Classes for containers?

Tags: c#

I'm having an issue creating something similar to this:

Container A has multiple Container B's. Those container B's in Container A have multiple Containers C, D, E, F.

Containers C, D, E, F reference both Container B and A.

This was the method that I was using prior:

```
public class ContainerA{
public string name {get; set;}
   public class ContainerB{
   public List<string> ContainerC {get; set;}
...
}
```

And then in my main, I did:

```
var Containers = new List<ContainerA>();
```

And I'm referencing a table for the values:

```
int i = 0;
for (int t = 0; t < table.count; t++){
Containers[i].name = table[t][0];
i++;
}
```

This becomes a problem later on when I reference the second table to insert ContainerB values if there's a match from one of it's columns to ContainerA.
Since table[t][1] contains multiple ContainerB values.
This was hard to explain but can anyone help? 
Thank you!

Comment: I think this needs more info, what's a table? You don't show a definition of it so that would be useful. What are you trying to achieve and why? Make sure you aren't asking an x/y question - e.g. forget about how you think you should solve the problem but let us know; what's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The table is a SQL query with multiple rows and columns. Col A contains ContainerA info, and Col B contains ContainerB info. So I just make sure that if ContainerA is matching values, then ContainerB is added to the object. There are multiple ContainerB's per ContainerA. Does that help somewhat?


The actual problem is this, I've got a SQL Query that uses inner joins, and is returning a table that is repeating it's columns far too often, and I'm trying to figure out a way to make it independent from the actual query in C#.

Comment: So you have joined SQL data as a single result set and you want to extract objects from the SQL data based on their relationships? Someone has already written a tool for this: check out Slapper.Automapper: https://github.com/SlapperAutoMapper/Slapper.AutoMapper - you might also consider using a MicroORM to grab your data into objects instead of tables/arrays, since Slapper works more intuitively with objects